# Postgres COPY file with encoding LATIN1 into table with encoding UTF

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding, copy, bulkinsert

I have a problem during bulk insert. I'm trying do bulk insert from file with encoding LATIN1 into table where database with encoding UTF8.

```
invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc33f
```

When I do SET CLIENT_ENCODING='LATIN1' and after do COPY from console, it works OK. but JDBC say me that he can't do SET CLIENT_ENCODING.

Please, could you suggest solution how I can workaround problem. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you send a `set client_encoding` statement as raw sql in jdbc?

Comment: yep, as sql query execute by means jdbc. Aslo I tried add settter into stored procedure before COPY operation but the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set [`allowEncodingChanges`](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html) connection parameter to true to allow (temporarily) changing client encoding to LATIN1. According to [Table 22-2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html#AEN30737) PostgreSQL should handle automatic character set conversion between LATIN1 (client) and UTF8 (server).

> The client_encoding setting is set by
> the driver and should not be altered.
> If the driver detects a change it will
> abort the connection. **There is one
> legitimate exception** to this behavior
> though, **using the COPY command** on a
> file residing on the server's
> filesystem. The only means of
> specifying the encoding of this file
> is by altering the client_encoding
> setting.
>
> Enable this only if you need
> to override the client encoding when
> doing a copy.

Comment: Thanks! It's a solution.May be you know, what is consequence for allowEncodingChanges = true.